# django + uwsgi + nginx does not deliver any http response, says nothing

Tags: django, nginx

The system seems to be running, but I don't get any normal HTTP response:

```
Romans-MacBook-Pro:kariera-centr.ru rreimche$ telnet yozh-studio.com 80
Trying 46.101.236.181...
Connected to yozh-studio.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: yozh-studio.com

Connection closed by foreign host.
Romans-MacBook-Pro:kariera-centr.ru rreimche$ telnet yozh-studio.com 80
Trying 46.101.236.181...
Connected to yozh-studio.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: yozh-studio.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;
        q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

uwsgi.log stays just as it was after starting the service:

```
[rreimche@rreimche-web hedgehog]$ sudo cat log/uwsgi.log 
[sudo] password for rreimche: 
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.11.2 (64bit) on [Tue Nov  3 15:57:03 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) on 29 October 2015 19:27:56
os: Linux-3.10.0-123.8.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 22 19:06:58 UTC 2014
nodename: rreimche-web
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/sites
detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi
chdir() to /var/www/hedgehog/code
your processes number limit is 7870
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /run/uwsgi/hedgehog.sock fd 3
setuid() to 1003
Python version: 2.7.5 (default, Jun 24 2015, 00:41:19)  [GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)]
Set PythonHome to /home/hedgehog/.virtualenv/hedgehog
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x25c8c10
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 436608 bytes (426 KB) for 5 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x25c8c10 pid: 2938 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 2938)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 2943, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 2944, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 2945, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 2946, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 2947, cores: 1)
```

the nginx logs are empty:

```
[rreimche@rreimche-web hedgehog]$ sudo cat log/access.log 
[rreimche@rreimche-web hedgehog]$ sudo cat log/error.log 
[rreimche@rreimche-web hedgehog]$
```

CONFIGURATIONS (CentOS 7):

/etc/uwsgi/sites/hedgehog.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
project = hedgehog
username = hedgehog
base = /var/www/%(username)/code

chdir = /var/www/hedgehog/code
home = /%(username)/.virtualenv/%(username)
module = %(username).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

uid = %(username)
socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
chown-socket = %(username):nginx
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
logto = /var/www/%(username)/log/uwsgi.log
```

/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c 'mkdir -p /run/uwsgi; chown hedgehog:nginx/run/uwsgi'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/hedgehog.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yozh-studio.com, www.yozh-studio.com;

    access_log /var/www/hedgehog/log/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/hedgehog/log/error.log;

    location = favicaon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/hedgehog/static;
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/hedgehog.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems, it's nginx not forwarding requests to uwsgi. I checked the main access.log of my nginx and found this there: [my.own.ip.address] - - [08/Nov/2015:20:58:44 +0100] "GET /some-path HTTP/1.1" 444 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/601.2.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.1 Safari/601.2.7" "-". 444 means the HTTP response code saying "the server has returned no information to the client and closed the connection". Why is nginx doing that?

Comment: I have a "return 444;" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf for default server but I do not request just my IP address, I use also server name (I open the website simply in browser). So it's still not clear, why I get 444 from nginx...

Comment: I solved the issue: it was in config for the server name in nginx. I had this line: server_name yozh-studio.com, www.yozh-studio.com; When I changed it to server_name "yozh-studio.com;" it started to work like a charm.